# std::remove_reference not removing the reference

Tags: c++

This prints the cout, which means the type of `T` is `int&`:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <sys/types.h>
using namespace std;
using var_t = std::variant<int, long, double, std::string>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<var_t> vec = {10};
    for(auto v : vec) {
        std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
            using T = decltype(arg);
            // if (std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference<T>, int>) {
            if (std::is_same_v<T, int&>) {
                cout<<"int "<<arg<<endl;
            }
        }, v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if I apply `std::remove_reference`, it doesn't print.

In fact, it doesn't matter if I use `int`, `int&` or `int&&`, cout doesn't get printed.

```
#include <vector>
#include <sys/types.h>
using namespace std;
using var_t = std::variant<int, long, double, std::string>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<var_t> vec = {10};
    for(auto v : vec) {
        std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
            using T = decltype(arg);
            if (std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference<T>, int>) {
                cout<<"int "<<arg<<endl;
            }
        }, v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? With `main()` and all required #include. What is `var_t`?

Comment: **if I use int, int& or int&&** Where do you use them? You have two `auto`, at which one?

Comment: updated the question with full example

Comment: @273K I gave 2 examples, one which use int and another which use int&, and I meant that if i use std::remove_reference, then it doesn't matter if I compare it with int, int&, int&&, value is false, i think the question is pretty self-explanatory, I added the full repro step though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a typo, but fascinating enough to answer: you forgot `_t` to extract the type from `std::remove_reference`.

```
if (std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>, int>) {
//                                      ^~
```

Why does it compile? Well, `std::remove_reference` is also a class. It's perfectly fine thing to pass as `std::is_same` template argument, so the compiler doesn't object. But what you really want is the `type` member of this class (which is also conveniently provided as `_t` alias).

Comment: oh i see, thanks this worked...I didn't notice that